# Pre-Load or Pre-Buffer .mp4 video in android app development

Tags: android, video, uri, buffer, mp4

I am building an app that is successfully displaying an MP4 video file onButtonClick. I want to pre-buffer or preload the video's URI (remote url) so that it doesn't delay the playing of the video once the button is clicked. I want it to click and play right away, so pre-loading or buffering on the app launch splash screen seems like a fitting solution. Only thing is I don't know how. I have tons of Android Books, but hardly any of them cover buffering at all or they only cover audio.

Can anyone let me know how to buffer the video on a previous activity?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to only buffer a portion of the video?
If not, you could download the MP4 to flash memory then play like a file.

Comment: Not sure, but did you try calling start then immediately call pause or stop?

Answer (score 4):

Google released ExoPlayer which provides a higher level for media playing : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

It supports different state such as buffering in background :

```
// 1. Instantiate the player.
player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);
// 2. Construct renderers.
MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer = …
MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = ...
// 3. Inject the renderers through prepare.
player.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);
```

I used it in my own project and it seems pretty efficient. Also Google made a Full Demo of the player : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/full which is more powerfull than simple demo.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Hugo. Id like to create a video playlist application. The videos will be over IP. Id like the transition between each video to be instant. Before a video finishes playing, id like to prebuffer the upcoming next video. Should I use two instances of the Exoplayer? Is this possible? Would you recommend this approach?

Comment: I'm not sur that exoplayer support many instance but I'm sure that there should be a way to do it. I you consider using ExoPlayer, you can open an Issue on the github : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: how do you preload a video with this player?

Comment: @user1974368 the `player.prepare(...)` as stated in the answer will do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MediaPlayer for preparing the video, like this:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(<implementation of MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener>);

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(dataSource);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

After the call `prepareAsync()` the mediaplayer will buffer your video.
The `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.onPrepared()` will tell you if the mediaplayer is ready to play yet.

Just check the prepared flag and call `mediaplayer.start()` when you click your button "onButtonClick"

Comment: thanks for this answer. Id like to create a video playlist that will prebuffer the upcoming video. Should I use 2 MediaPlayers for this? Id like the transition between each video to be instant. I was thinking of alternating between the 2 players. Would you recommend this approach?

Comment: You may do that approach or you can create a "Preload Helper" class that pre-download for upcomming video.

Comment: If video A is playing and I set data source to video B and call prepareAsync(), will that stop running video A in the mediaPlayer? By Preload Helper class, will that use a second mediaPlayer ? Also, what are your thoughts on using the new ExoPlayer android class? Thanks!

Comment: To stop Video A by calling `stop()` then set data source to B and call prepareAsync(). Preload Helper class I meant you create a class that pre download upcoming video in background. When ready, set the media player source to the predownloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

The native Android Browser doesn't buffer the media files (audio or video), so there is no way to do it on HTML5. As @bradenV2 said, you could copy the file to memory (you could use Phonegap if it is an App).